# Can Two Binary Search Trees Have the Same Values but Different Structures?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Define a BST as: all left descendants <= n < all right descendants.

Then is it possible to build two binary search trees with different structures but the same exact values? Duplicate values are allowed.

Comment: A binary search tree can be balanced (or it can be unbalanced).  Balancing an unbalanced tree changes the structure while keeping the other natures of the binary search tree.  See [(algorithm for) keeping a binary search tree balanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there can be various BSTs consisting of the same numbers.
Let's take the numbers 1, 2, 3.

If the order you add them to the tree is 1, 2, 3 then the tree would have 1 as root, 2 as it's right node and 3 as 2's right node.

If the order is 2, 1, 3 then the tree would have 2 as the root, 1 as the left node and 3 as the right node.

If the order is 3, 1, 2 then the tree would have 3 as the root, 1 as the left node and 2 as the right node of 1.
etc.

Comment: And even with two numbers 1 and 2, you can have either 1 or 2 as the root.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The structure of the BST Is based on the order jn which the elements are added. So, if you use the same elements, but populate in a different order, you will get a different tree.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing it. Can you give an example?

Comment: @JoshPearce Sure, imagine a tree from (1,2,3). It's either a balanced tree, or a chain. If you have 4 numbers, then you can have 2 different balanced trees with the same values (pick one of the 2 middle elements as the root)

Comment: That depends on the insertion algorithm obviously.